# Mistakes in applications for PhD in CS

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, cv

I made a mistake in my grad application.

I have around 10-15 publications/under review/conferences put together.

For 2 papers, I didn't add all the author names.
For 1 paper, I didn't provide the latest version of the paper. Gave the wrong journal name. (for the new submission of this paper, only the format is changed and nothing else).

I have mailed the university regarding the same.

Does this mistake mean that they will disqualify me from the pool? or Does this show my lack of attention, and because of that they won’t bother to check anything my application at all?

The mistakes are in my CV.

Comment: The university was extremely thoughtful and has updated the application with the new files I had sent :)

Comment: I have so many works because of working multiple internships at once. Also, most of them are concentrated in two domains, so one work just led to another. They are of good quality and published at quite a few good places. But there are a few posters too along with a few under review as mentioned. I also didn't mention the number to brag or get a PhD. That was just for context.

Answer (score 3):

If you are clogging the email of your future supervisor with such requests, corrections, second thoughts and generally "anxious" requests, you can be almost sure that you will be discarded.

On the other hand, if you applied through some formal way (application portal, HR email, secretary of the professor), it is good to (try to) rectify every error as soon as possible.

Do not stress out because chances of getting a PhD are infinitesimaly small, give them all your concentration and efforts **before** delivering the application (to avoid the mistakes you made), then when submitted, **forget** about them and for your mental health consider them always rejected, unless proven contrary but ... good luck with your applications!

Comment: "chances of getting a PhD are infinitesimaly small" what? This isn't true at all. Least of all for someone applying with a publication record like OP's.

Comment: @CSSTUDENT you are strongly evaluating a candidate to PhD on the basis of publication record, which is one of the worst thing to do. Stop it. Thanks.

Comment: How else do you think a prospective PhD candidate should be evaluated, if not by their capacity for research? And what is an illustrious publication record, if not strong evidence for the capacity to do research?

Comment: @CSSTUDENT We do not know the background. Such a strong publication simply means the candidate was in group publishing a lot, which can be a good thing or an awful thing, we cannot say anything without context. Plus, I want evidence that a potential PhD student is able to push that 1 difficult paper he cares of, asking the right support of colleagues, not that he can contribute to 10/15 different papers.

Comment: Even if the contributions are small, I fail to see how it can be an "awful" thing -- it is certainly better than nothing at all, which is the case for most PhD applicants.

Answer (score 2):

> I have around 10-15 publications/under review/conferences put together.
> For 2 papers, I didn't add all the author names. For 1 paper, I didn't provide the latest version of the paper. Gave the wrong journal name. (for the new submission of this paper, only the format is changed and nothing else).

These sound like minor inaccuracies in a PhD application that will have no effect on the decision made. I wouldn't worry much about them and I wouldn't bother the potential supervisor either.